# Crispy forms performance issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I'm using crispy_forms django app to apply bootstrap forms in my Django app, but after deployment I found there is a performance bottleneck and my template rending took 97% of my response time, this is bad and I want to know if there is any solution for this.

[image: Rending Time]

Note: This is my template settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': [
                (
                    'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                    ]
                ),
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: did you check before you started using crispy forms?

Comment: [Django template cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) may help.